# Using os.walk to read files

Tags: python, file, directory, os.walk, subdirectory

I'm trying to access files rooted in subdirectories of a main directory. For this purpose, I am using `os.walk()`. I am able to successfully reach the file names and am able to store that in a list. However, when I try to open these files using the `open(filename, 'r')`, I get an error telling me that no such file or directory exits.

I think the problem here is that I am only accessing the `'names'` and not the actual files itself. My code looks like this:

```
list_of_files = {}
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in 
os.walk("C:\\Users\\Akarshkb\\Desktop\\cs361hw\\HMP_Dataset"):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'): 
            list_of_files[filename] = os.sep.join([dirpath, filename])
            file = open(filename, 'r')
            file.read()
            file.close()
print (list_of_files)
```

And I get the following error:

```
        `FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call 
    last)
    <ipython-input-40-10ae3e92446a> in <module>()
          4         if filename.endswith('.txt'):
          5             list_of_files[filename] = os.sep.join([dirpath, 
    filename])
    ----> 6             file = open(filename, 'r')
          7             file.read()
          8             file.close()

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Accelerometer-2011- 
   04-11-13-28-18-brush_teeth-f1.txt'`
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `os.path.join(dirpath, filename)` or for *Python 3.4+* `pathlib.Path(dirpath, filename)`

Answer (score 5):

You should not be ignoring the `dirpath` value.

Try this:

```
        file = open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), 'r')
```